# Moving from c#.net to node.js, recommendations for design patterns

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, mean-stack

I am working on transitioning an app. from c# to node.js and am trying to find where complex logic should go?  For c#, ddd is a good fit where logic would normally exist in the domain and logic that was not a good fit for the domain itself could go into domain services, etc.  With the way mean is structured and javascript in general, this seems to be an awkward fit.  Doable but awkward.  The app. I am working on is a social network, so I am using the microservices approach.  In the node.js world, what are the preferred approaches to handling complex business logic?  What is the preferred folder structure for mean applications?  Are there preferred approaches over patterns and practices like ddd, service layer, repository, etc.?

Comment: This is opinion based question. You are not gonna get the answer you are looking for. Since you mentioned mean stack I would recommend you to search for "express directory structure" or something like that and you will find endless recommendations. Look through the results and decide what's best for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the default structure provided by http://mean.io as that will setup the well structured directory hierarchy. Write all your services in controller directory.